# How to get values of textbox from dynamically generated form in meteor, while the number of textbox is not fixed

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I want to get the value of textboxes from a dynamically generated form and store in database. Number of textboxes are not fixed. The form is inside a template.

```
    <template name="product">
     <input type="text" id="txt1">
     <input type="text" id="txt2">
     .......
     .......
     <button id="CreateNewProduct">Create new product</button>
    </template>
```

I want to insert textbox values in "product" collection.
I have just shown two textboxes in here for reference. It may be 3,4,5,...... upto n number. It may contain checkbox and radio also.

Can you suggest me how to proceed with this task?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for your problem? I'm having similar issue and would love to hear how did you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over the existing input elements and match their corresponding `id`s with their `n`th standing in the form as a reference for specific property of the Product collection.

```
Template.product.events({
    "submit form": function(event, template) {
        var product = {};

        template.$("input").each(function(index) {
            product["property"+index] = template.$("input#txt"+index).val();
        });

        Product.insert(product);
    }

})
```

Comment: We are capturing the submit event, iterating over the input elements and assigning their values to a property of a product instance, and inserting the instance to a collection. Note that you will need to come up with a way to map the inputs to specific properties of product if you want to name the properties something other than "property1", "property2", .... "propertyn"